# hide footer when keyboard appear

Tags: html, css

How i can hide footer when keyboard appear? when i click on any input in my phone. footer rises above i do not know how i can fix this problem

codes `

```css
footer { 
   margin-top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
     position:absolute;

    height: 50px;
    background-color: #D03F42;
}

footer p {
    text-align: center;
    color: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
 
<footer> 
   
    <p>&copy;My web site</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JS code like this one: 
`$("input").on("click touch", function(){
$("footer").hide();
});`

Comment: i am not have any Experience about javascript but that is right <script>$("input").on("click touch", function(){
$("footer").hide();
});
     </script>

Comment: That's jQuery. You should include it in your HTML page in order to use it:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: but that is code not working  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"> $("input").on("click touch", function(){
$("footer").hide();
});</script>
           <style> can you help me ??

Comment: The jQuery script tag needs to be added into the HTML code. The code I showed you should be added inside a SCRIPT tag in the html code. 

Example:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("input").on("click touch", function(){
$("footer").hide();
});
</script>
<!-- insert below the rest of your HTML code -->`